# data stored in Sharedpreference lost when exiting app

Tags: javascript, java, android

I'm working on a step counter app.The steps are increasing gradually,and I want to save step data in sharedpreference but when I return to home page and restart the app the step data which i thought it should be saved in sharedprefernce just disappear and reset to 0.
Following is part of my code. How can I solve this problem?Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String finalstep="";
    String valuestring1= null;

    private static final String step = "STEP";

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    int date = Integer.parseInt(strDate);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void readData(){
        settings = getSharedPreferences(step,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        textSteps.setText(settings.getString(valuestring1, ""));
    }

    public void resetSteps(View v) {
        String strDate1 = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        int date1 = Integer.parseInt(strDate1);
        if(date1==date) {
            readData();
            textSteps.setText(valuestring1);
        }
        else{
            date=date1;
            numSteps = 0;
            textSteps.setText(String.valueOf(numSteps));
        }
    }
    public void saveData(){
        String s = String.valueOf(finalstep);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(step,0);
        settings.edit()
                .putString(s, valuestring1).commit();
    }

    public void pressed (View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.exit) {
  saveData();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In saveData while adding value to sharedpreference you have to pass a key as

```
settings.edit().putString("KEY_STEP", s).commit();
```

and while getting the sharedpreference value you have to fetch as

```
settings.getString("KEY_STEP", "")
```

Comment: The key while fetching and putting is used in wrong position.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes you made. You are placing the key is a wrong position. Have also made the sharedPreference a member class

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

String finalstep="";
String valuestring1= "STEP_VALUE";

private static final String step = "STEP";

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
int date = Integer.parseInt(strDate);

private SharedPreferences settings;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    settings = getSharedPreferences(step, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void readData(){
    textSteps.setText(settings.getString(valuestring1, ""));
}

public void resetSteps(View v) {
    String strDate1 = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    int date1 = Integer.parseInt(strDate1);
    if(date1==date) {
        readData();
        textSteps.setText(valuestring1);
    }
    else{
        date=date1;
        numSteps = 0;
        textSteps.setText(String.valueOf(numSteps));
    }
}
public void saveData(){
    String s = String.valueOf(finalstep);
    settings.edit().putString(valuestring1, s).apply();
}

public void pressed (View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.exit) {
        saveData();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the updated code with highlights:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 String finalstep = "abc";/* assign some value*/
 String valuestring1 = null;

 private static final String step = "STEP";

 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
 String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
 int date = Integer.parseInt(strDate);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void readData() {
    settings = getSharedPreferences(step, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  /*
  accessing with same value which was used at time of saving i.e. s
   */

    textSteps.setText(settings.getString(finalstep, ""));//

}

public void resetSteps(View v) {
    String strDate1 = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    int date1 = Integer.parseInt(strDate1);
    if (date1 == date) {
        readData();
        textSteps.setText(valuestring1);
    } else {
        date = date1;
        numSteps = 0;
        textSteps.setText(String.valueOf(numSteps));
    }
}

public void saveData() {
    String s = String.valueOf(finalstep);/* you can directly use finalstep no need of conversion and also no need to declare locally directly use finalstep*/
    settings = getSharedPreferences(step, 0);
    settings.edit()
            .putString(s, valuestring1).commit();
}

public void pressed(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.exit) {
        saveData();
    }
}
```

}

as you were storing values in other key and trying to find with other key.

secondly i'm not getting what exactly you want to store, what ever you want to store just assign that value to valuestring1, as **null** is stored in valuestring1 and you are trying to store it and get it back.

Comment: Hi,I want to store the current steps into sharedpreference,and after exiting the app, i think the steps i've stored should appear,but it didn't.

Comment: For example,if the current step is 27,  after exiting the app and restart again, i want the number 27 still there but it reset to 0

Comment: valuestring1 set this to your value and the save in sharedprefrence in your code i am not able to identify when you are assigning value to valuestring1.